# How do I match parentheses arguments with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I match this: `foo(bar,baz)` getting `bar,baz` as the match with regex in javascript?

This is the regular expression:

```
([A-z]+([A-z,]+))
```

Comment: show your current regex. but you probably need to escape the characters `\(` and `\)`.

Comment: Rather than add to comments it should be added the question so the question has all the details. I did it for you this time.

Comment: **Warning:** Do not use `[A-z]` in a regex.  To match any ASCII letter regardless of case, use `[A-Za-z]` or `[a-z]` with the ignore-case modifier selected.  `[A-z]` matches all the letters plus several punctuation characters whose code points lie between `Z` and `a`.  It's actually equivalent to ``[A-Z\[\\\]^_`a-z]``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you *could* use regex:

```
var str = 'foo(bar,baz)';
str.match(/\((.*)\)/)[1]; // "bar,baz"
```

But why not just slice the string instead?

```
str.slice(str.indexOf('(')+1, str.indexOf(')')); // same result
```

Comment: i would suggest a non greedy or more exclusive "wildcard". i usually use  'foo(bar,baz)'.split(/[()]/)[1].trim().split(/\s*,\s*/) to get a nice clean array of formal parameters.